# Getting an error filtering records by month SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code where I am trying to find the records for May and trying to group them by website. But getting this error. Any idea why it's saying no function matches?

```
SELECT
ad.site, SUM(e.clicks) AS totalclicks
FROM Extable e 
INNER JOIN Ads ad ON e.ad_id = ad.ad_id
WHERE month(ad.Create_Time) = 5
Group by ad.site;
```

But I am getting this error

```
ERROR: function month(date) does not exist
LINE 4: WHERE month(ad.Create_Time) = 5
^

HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

SQL state: 42883
Character: 107
```

Comment: be sure to "upvote" and "accept" auditt _98's answer

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html) did you find the `month()` function?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)'s the documentation of date/time function for PostgreSQL.
Seems like you have to use EXTRACT() or DATE_PART()

```
date_part('hour', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40')

extract(hour from timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40')
```

Comment: You beat me to it: I was about to suggest `extract(month from ad.Create_Time)`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Comment: No, the data type is date. I googled the error and saw this.
"matter of schema vs. schema search_path. The function is created in the default schema of the creating user. If that's not in the search_path of the current user, it's not visible"

I am not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: @RishanDante that is the case if you have created a custom function with name `month`. not for the inbuilt function. AFAIK there is no in built function with name `month`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt named `month`.

You should write your query like below:

```
SELECT
ad.site, SUM(e.clicks) AS totalclicks
FROM Extable e 
INNER JOIN Ads ad ON e.ad_id = ad.ad_id
WHERE 
extract (month from ad.Create_Time) = 5 --your month
and 
extract (month from ad.Create_Time) = 2021 --year
Group by ad.site;
```

apart from month you may check for year also(based on your requirement)

Answer (score 0):

Using EXTRACT() works great and is supported by many databases, including [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract).

But you could also create a MONTH()-function in PostgreSQL to mimic this MySQL function in PostgreSQL. You need 3 functions, one for each datatype (date, timestamp and timestamp with time zone):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION month(IN i_date DATE) 
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE
AS
$$
    SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM $1);
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION month(IN i_timestamp TIMESTAMP) 
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE
AS
$$
    SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM $1);
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION month(IN i_timestamptz TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) 
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE
AS
$$
    SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM $1);
$$;

-- Tests:
SELECT month(CURRENT_DATE); -- date

SELECT month(localtimestamp); -- timestamp

SELECT month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); -- timestamp with time zone
```

Comment: . . `EXTRACT()` doesn't just work great.  It is the SQL Standard function for this purpose.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I know ;-) But sometimes you have to migrate a lot of code that doesn't use The Standard. That's when a work a round might be handy